# Oriented bounding box vs. enclosing cylinder

Tags: geometry, 3d

Say we have a 3D cloud of dots. An oriented bounding box (OBB) can be constructed around them. It usually has a longest edge. Let's call a line parallel to the longest edge and passing through the center of OBB - axis of OBB.

On the other hand, there exists an enclosing cylinder with minimal diameter. It will roughly have a shape and orientation that of OBB.

The question is: is there a proof, that axes of OBB and the enclosing cylinder are always parallel?

Comment: Is the OBB the box with the smallest volume that can enclose the dots?

Comment: Yes, like this https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18264-minimal-bounding-box. For 2D here is a diagram https://jkhub.org/topic/9066-bounding-boxes/